# Access data in several matlab files

Tags: python, matlab, loading

I am currently trying to get data from several MATLab files. I am reading from a directory where I have all my data saved. I can read the data (ex. Gain) within the a Matlab file individually. I would like to add a for loop to read through all the files (different data but same format) the same "Gain," but every time I try to write a for loop, it gives me this error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import scipy.io as sio
import scipy 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

#directory where all data will be stored
dataDir="C:/Users/me/Desktop/Data/"
Files=[] #list of files
lenght=len(Files)
for file in os.listdir(dataDir):
    Files.append(scipy.io.loadmat(dataDir+file))

#initialize arrays
results=[lenght]
Gain=[lenght]


for files in Files:
    results[files]=Files[files]['results']
    #Gain in side of my results key in the file. I can read it in only one file
    Gain[files]=results[files]['PowerDomain'][0,0]['Gain'][0,0]

    print (files)
```

Comment: You have written "MATLAB" three times in three different ways :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two separate issues with the code that are causing this error:

(1) Your code is initializing `results` and `Gain` to length-1 lists. Instead (based on what it appears you're trying to do), you should be initializing them to length `lenght` (sic*) lists, i.e.`results = [None] * lenght` and `Gain = [None] * lenght`.

(2) `Files` is an array of dicts. In each loop iteration, `files` (sic**) becomes one of those dicts. If you instead want `files` to be an index into the `Files` list, then your loop should be `for files in range(0, lenght):`.

Alternatively, if you want `results` and `Gain` to be dicts, you can initialize them as `results = {}` and similarly for `Gain`, and then in each iteration you can set their values like `results(<filename>) = ...` (where `<filename>` is the current file name.

Also, if you want to keep the loop of the form `for files in Files:`, that's fine, but keep in mind that `files` will actually be an element of `Files` rather than an index into `Files`.

* From a style perspective, you should correct the spelling of `lenght` to `length`.

** Also from a style perspective, you should probably not name the list index `files`; perhaps something like `f`. But this is more subjective.